# Micro-Controller Operating System with GUI

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microchip, .net-micro-framework, java

I'm looking for embedded OS for w micro-controller, it's not clear until now for me what'll be  the controller type, but my first priority is to found an OS with GUI can be written in C# or any .NET family or JAVA. I found some good operating system like:
[emWIN](http://www.segger.com/emwin.html), [easyGUI](http://www.easygui.com/), PEG
but all of them could be customized in C++, Any help please about same OSs but not in C++.

and due to I'm new in embedded systems developing and until now not clear with the main structure, is it possible to let developers create applications and install it on my embedded system or the main structure only allow to customize the software and burn it to micro-controller, or in other words.. in advanced mood. Can I create SDKs for my embedded system or the only way to create a software on an embedded system is to customize my OS with my applications and burn it.. Thanks and sorry if am not clear with that field but am trying to collect a lot about it.

Comment: cross posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999707/micro-controller-operating-system-with-gui

Comment: Mohamed, please don't cross post. Post your question only once, on the SE site where you expect it fits best.

Comment: Mohamed, [Here are 39 low cost Linux friendly boards](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/06/26/list-of-39-low-cost-linux-friendly-boards-and-products/) Hope it helps you.

Comment: @stevenvh is that rule or just your suggestion? Because I would often expect different and possibly useful answers to the same question at multiple SE sites.

Comment: @kenny - cross posting is being frowned upon, not just by me. I'm not sure about possibly different useful answers. If they decide on SO that it doesn't fir there and they migrate it here we'll have it twice. It wouldn't be the first time. I think the chance of noise is greater.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this question is not capable of being answered. You don't need to consider what OS you're going to use at first. First, you need to consider what kind of micro-controller you're going to be using.

Various ARM CPUs will be perfectly capable of running a "OS" in .Net
However, AVR and PIC and such will not be able to use even the most micro of .Net frameworks.

Second, you need to consider why you're needing to use .Net. The .Net micro framework will have a lot more overhead than a direct native program. If using .Net is only a priority because you don't want to learn C++, you probably just need to man up and learn C or C++.

And what kind of OS are you looking for? An RTOS, or a more general purpose OS, such as Linux? You're going to have a hard time finding an OS of much complexity implemented in C#, because of the reason I said above.

Comment: Okay, I'm IT student preparing for my GP, it's not matter of C++ I can write Assembly, C, C++, C#, Basic, Java. it's all about some constrains I have, So thanks for your answer I'll look first for the Microcontroller that fits my task then the OS.

Answer (score 3):

### If you like C# you can use Netduino

[image]

It has a **Free** IDE supported by Microsoft you can [download here](http://netduino.com/downloads/).

> Netduino is an open source electronics platform using the .NET Micro
>   Framework.
>
> Featuring a 32-bit microcontroller and a rich development environment.
>   Suitable for engineers and hobbyists alike

- Atmel 32-bit microcontroller
- Speed: 48MHz, ARM7
- Code Storage: 128 KB
- RAM: 60 KB

It is cheap but some accessories can be expensive (But you can make your own cheaper)

Answer (score 3):

### How about a $35 computer?

[image]

The [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) is the latest viral trend for cheap but extremely powerful "Micro Controller" The supported OS is a special version of Debian for ARM6 but it can run almost anything the normal Debian does and also has Input/Output pins.

Most of software is also **Free**

> The Raspberry Pi is a credit-card sized computer that plugs into your
>   TV and a keyboard. It’s a capable little PC which can be used for many
>   of the things that your desktop PC does, like spreadsheets,
>   word-processing and games. It also plays high-definition video. We
>   want to see it being used by kids all over the world to learn
>   programming.

- CPU, 700 MHz ARM (ARM11)
- GPU, VideoCore IV, OpenGL ES 2.0, 1080p30 h.264/MPEG-4 AVC
- RAM 256mb (depends on model too)
- Storage, Unlimited (Whatever you connect to it) (Priamry SD-Card, USB and Network)

[Ask the dedicated Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange Community for more questions...](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Or one of the slightly more expensive BeagleBoard and BeagleBones.

Comment: Yes.. or one of those too :)

Comment: Also, mono is completely supported on it correct? So there's your C# fix as well

Comment: @Earlz yes, I believe there's a .NET Mono implementation for Debian builds on one or both of those boards.

Answer (score 3):

### ARIA ARM9 SoM

[image]

A very similar product to the Raspberry Pi but runs on an ARM architecture that is fully supported by many Linux distributions. The nice thing about this is that you make the rest of the circuit- SO you can embedd a 2GB flash and run your own build of linux with API's on it while offering LAN, SPI, GPIO,I2C etc.

> [Aria G25](http://www.acmesystems.it/aria) is a small SoM (System-on-Module) thought of for hardware
>   designers who want to reduce the development time of OEM Linux
>   embedded devices. Aria G25 can be used either as a SMD module on a PCB
>   or as stand-alone module to wire directly to other modules.

- ARM9 @ 400Mhz
- 128 or 255 ram
- USB and LAN
- 0.3 watt power consumption
- 24 Euro's
- Fully expendable for you design!

Comment: Whoa, that's really cool. I think I'm gonna buy one of those to play with.

Comment: That's really cheap!

Answer (score 0):

If your target is an embedded Linux ARM board, then you can use **[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon/codetyphon-help)** to cross compile to it, or **[fpGUI](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm)** to have an on board compiler. Both use FPC compiler, so not your priority.